# Re-tried Future Not Completing

Tags: scala

Given this function, which retries an unevaluated `Future` **n** times:

```
scala>   def retry[A](x: Function0[Future[A]], n: Int): Future[A] = {
     |     if(n <= 0)
     |       x()
     |     else
     |       println("n" + n)
     |       x().recoverWith({ case _ => retry(x, n - 1) })
     |   }
retry: [A](x: () => scala.concurrent.Future[A], n: Int)scala.concurrent.Future[A]
```

I wrote a test method, `g`:

```
scala> def g: Function0[Future[Int]] = () => Future ( throw new RuntimeException("foo") )
g: () => scala.concurrent.Future[Int]
```

Then, I called `retry(g, 5)`:

```
scala> retry[Int](g, 5)
n5
n4
res25: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = Future(<not completed>)
n3
n2
n1
```

After getting this output, I waited 2 minutes, but the Future isn't showing up as having completed:

```
scala> res25
res28: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = Future(<not completed>)

scala> res25.value
res29: Option[scala.util.Try[Int]] = None
```

What's that about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR**: Always use brackets for `if` `else` statments.

You're `if` statment is misleading, here's what it looks like with brackets:

```
  def retry[A](x: Function0[Future[A]], n: Int): Future[A] = {
         if (n <= 0) {
           println("n" + n) //added this for clarity
           x()
         } else {
           println("n" + n)
         }
         x().recoverWith({ case _ => retry(x, n - 1) })
       }
```

Basically you're never reaching the final condition, you just keep incrementing `n` down and then returning `x().recoverWith({ case _ => retry(x, n - 1) })`

What you really want is this:

```
  def retry[A](x: Function0[Future[A]], n: Int): Future[A] = {
         if (n <= 0) {
           println("n" + n)
           x()
         } else {
           println("n" + n)
           x().recoverWith({ case _ => retry(x, n - 1) })
         }
       }
```